# CakePHP 2.x - Virtual fields max foreach items

Tags: php, cakephp, field, cakephp-2.2, paginator

**System**

- CakePHP 2.x

**Database**

```
Houses --> id, name
Visits --> id, date, house_id
```

**Models**

```
Visit belongsTo House
House hasMany Visit
```

**View**

- I have a view for all houses called houses/index.ctp.
- It lists each house with their id and their name.
- I also use the PaginatorHelper to sort my array.

**Issue**

- I'd like to see for each house last visit they had.
- This have to be sortable by the PaginatorHelper

**Tries**

- I thought that I could do it with virtualFields but I failed (it always returns the max value of all houses).

  `public $virtualFields = array('lastvisit' => 'SELECT MAX(visits.date) FROM visits, houses WHERE houses.id = visits.house_id GROUP BY house_id');`
- I tried to "cache" each max visit in a new column of Houses table but it's very dirty.

Thank you for helping.

Comment: What do you mean by `but I failed`? Any error messages?

Comment: I just edit the question to add the virtualfield I tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declaring a virtual field for this may be tricky, so I suggest you to add it on the fly whenever you need it.

So your `HousesController`'s index action will look like this:

```
public function index() {
    $this->House->virtualFields['last_visit'] = 'MAX(Visit.date)';
    $this->paginate = array(
        'House' => array(
            'group' => array('house_id'),
            'joins' => array(
                array(
                    'table' => 'visits',
                    'alias' => 'Visit',
                    'type' => 'INNER',
                    'conditions' => array(
                        'House.id = Visit.house_id',
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    );

    $this->set('houses', $this->paginate());
}
```

Notice you have to remove the `$publicFields` declaration from your model, and that I changed the name of the field to from `lastvisit` to `last_visit` to make it more Cake.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hey, seems like to be nice. I check and feedback.

Comment: the same thing, it's nice to list last visits but paginator is unable to sort according these dates.

Comment: @Starflash you're right, I just edited the code, it's cleaner now and allows sorting ;)

Comment: Thank you @luchomolina, it works ! I just changed the type of join to be able to see all houses (including having no visits).

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty simple if you use the [Containable](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html) behavior.

```
  $this->paginate['House'] = array(
    'contain' => array('Visit' => array('order' => 'date DESC')
  );
  $houses = $this->paginate('House');
```

I haven't tested this yet but it should be pretty close to what you need.  You may want to add a limit to `contain` so you only see the last x visits.

Comment: @luchomolina, I looked at your edit but I'm not sure if you are correct.  Look at the following example: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html#using-containable-with-pagination

Comment: That's interesting, I edited it based on tests I'm running. I have a sandbox for Stackoverflow questions :P and running your code throws this notice (not error, sorry): "Indirect modification of overloaded property HousesController::$paginate has no effect" – maybe someone should fix the bakery?

Comment: Well, it seems like to be an interesting way to solve the problem. I can get all data but as @luchomolina said, the doesn't sort this column.

Comment: This feature is very useful, I didn't know it. Thanks.